# Find indices of elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list with elements, while some of these elements can be repeated. For example, `a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. I want to find indices of all of these elements. Output should be like: `For element 1, indices are [1, 5, 9]. For element 2, indices are [2, 6, 10] etc...`

Can somebody please tell me how to do that? Note, code should be general as much as possible.

Comment: Python lists are numbered from `0`, so your expectation of indicies is somewhat wrong.

Comment: @devnull, thanks for pointing out that. But, I know that already. Thought of using indices starting from 1, because of better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a pretty general means:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> dct = {x:[] for x in lst}
>>> for x,y in enumerate(lst, 1):
...     dct[y].append(x)
...
>>> dct
{1: [1, 5, 9], 2: [2, 6, 10], 3: [3, 7, 11], 4: [4, 8, 12]}
>>>
```

Note however that Python indexes start at 0, so the list for 1 *should* be `[0, 4, 8]`, the list for 2 `[1, 5, 9]`, etc.  However, since you want the indexes to be +1, I set `enumerate` to start at 1.

---

The above solution uses pure Python without any imports.  However, if you import `collections.defaultdict`, you can increase the performance:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dct = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x,y in enumerate(lst, 1):
...     dct[y].append(x)
...
>>> dct
{1: [1, 5, 9], 2: [2, 6, 10], 3: [3, 7, 11], 4: [4, 8, 12]}
>>>
```

Comment: You can improve your solution with a defaultdict: from collections import defaultdict; dct = defaultdict(list)

Answer (score 2):

As long as the item is hashable, then:

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
dd = defaultdict(list)
for idx, item in enumerate(data):
    dd[item].append(idx)

# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [0, 4, 8], 2: [1, 5, 9], 3: [2, 6, 10], 4: [3, 7, 11]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like this:

```
def get_indexes(my_array, item):
    return [i for i, e in enumerate(my_array) if e == item]
```

Using one of your examples:

```
>>> print get_indexes([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
[1, 5, 9]
```

Comment: Change `a` to `my_array`, also it will not print as he asked since it's start from 0 and not from 1.

Answer (score 1):

Simple Example Using [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]    

myIndexes = [i for i,value in enumerate(list) if value == 1]

print myIndexs
```

> [0, 4, 8]

At your example you said:

> For element 1, indices are [1, 5, 9]

You actually wanted index + 1! pay attention! Lists start from 0.

So to get index + 1 you can do:

```
myIndexes = [i+1 for i,value in enumerate(list) if value == 1]

print myIndexs
```

> [1, 5, 9]

Answer (score 0):

`numpy` can be useful for something like this:

```
>>>> import numpy as np
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> np.where(np.array(a) == 1)[0]
array([0, 4, 8])
```